# Hiding the room names in Altium

Tags: altium

I'm working on a PCB design in Altium Designer, and I'm trying to hide the names of the rooms. I've tried searching for a solution online, but I haven't been able to find anything.

I'm using the Room feature to group different components together, but I don't want the room names to be visible on the PCB. I would prefer to have the rooms only visible in the PCB Inspector panel.

Does anyone know how to hide the names of rooms in Altium Designer?

I would appreciate any help that you can provide.

Comment: This link will take you, with a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: [https://forum.live.altium.com/](https://forum.live.altium.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide rooms and their names by clicking the eye next to Rooms in the **View Configuration** panel under **Object Visibility**:

[image: View Configuration panel, Object Visibility]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately this way just will hide all of Rooms and they will be hidden as well

Comment: Isn't that what you asked for?